# Write list objects to new line with spaces inbetween

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I'm rubbish at explaining things so I'm just going to let the code do the talking. This is a section of code I have

```
PIDages.Sort();
lollist.WriteLine();
foreach (int a in PIDages)
{
    lollist.Write(a + "  ");   
}
PIDages.Clear();
```

This code is repeated many times. At the moment it will output the each list on a new line in the following format

```
13*SPACE*  
13 13*SPACE*
1 2 8*SPACE*
```

Is there an easy fix to not have the space character at the end of every line?

Comment: remove the space in your lollist.Write line....

Comment: No that won't help because I need all integers on the SAME line with spaces to seperate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the string.Join function

```
lollist.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", PIDages));
```

I'm currently not sure if a cast is necessary, in C# 2.0 the syntax would be

```
lollist.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", PIDages.Select(a => a.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Cheers.

Comment: Cast wasn't necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

You could first concatenate the string and then use Trim to get rid of any spaces at the start or the end of the string.

A little bit like that:

```
string result = String.Empty;
foreach (int a in PIDages)
{
    result = result + a + " ";
}
result = result.Trim();
lollist.Write(result);
```

Comment: Yeah lol I thought of that just as you posted it but the other answer by user287107 is much nicer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip space at the end of string

You can try :

```
  PIDages.Sort();
  lollist.WriteLine();
  string sResult = string.Empty;

  foreach (int a in PIDages)
  {
      sResult += (a + "  ");   
  }
  lollist.Write(sResult.Trim());

  PIDages.Clear();
```

Comment: incorrect. why would an int value have a space within it?

Comment: It's returning the extra space because of the code inside the foreach section so this wouldn't help. thx for trying tho

Comment: Although this got me thinking that I could just append everything to a string then before I write it to the file use the Trim method.

Comment: yes my bad. I think OP requires list in which strings have no trailing space.

Comment: Yep that'll work but the answer by user287107 is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple?

```
bool add_space = false;
PIDages.Sort();
lollist.WriteLine();
foreach (int a in PIDages)
{
    if (add_space)
        lollist.Write("  ");
    else
        add_space = true;
    lollist.Write(a);
}
PIDages.Clear();
```